# Microsoft Edge check box values are not persisting when if we go some page and come-back to current page by using the browser back button?

Tags: checkbox, autocomplete, microsoft-edge

If we check the checkbox and go somewhere and come-back by using the browser back button, the values are persisting properly in (IE, FF and Chrome). But in Microsoft Edge check box values are not persisting.

Save the below content as 1.html and 2.html files.

I want to use the Microsoft Edge and even after go next page and come back to the current page still the check box values(checked) should persist.

1.html file.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Vertical (basic) form</h2>
  <form action="2.html">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email" autocomplete="on">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" name="pwd">
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="remember" name="remember" autocomplete="on"> Remember me</label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And 2.html file

```
<html>
<body>Testing browser back button and state of the checkbox value</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can somebody please look into this and help me on this.?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Please find the above attached link, for more information on the check-box and autocomplete property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a known issue in Edge. The situation is the same in my side and I also find a [bug report](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/4525797/). If you want to persist the value of checkbox in Edge, you can use [Web Storage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) to store the state/value.

You can add this script in 1.html:

```
<script>
    function myfunction() {
            //check whether the browser support storage
            if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {
                // Code for localStorage/sessionStorage.

                if (sessionStorage.checkboxstatus == 'true') {
                    document.getElementById("remember").checked = true;
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById("remember").checked = false;
                }

                //checkbox click event: use session storage to store the state
                document.getElementById("remember").addEventListener("click", function () {
                    if (document.getElementById("remember").checked) {
                        sessionStorage.checkboxstatus = true;
                    }
                    else {
                        sessionStorage.checkboxstatus = false;
                    }
                });

            } else {
                // Sorry! No Web Storage support..
                alert("No web storage support");
            }
        };
</script>
```

Then add `onload="myfunction();"` in `<body>` tag. The result is like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your comments/suggestions.I have tried in ie-edge-dev(chromium) browser the functionality working as we expected.

Comment: Do you know?, When we will expect the Microsoft-IE-Edge-Chromium browser coming into market.?

Comment: As far as I know, Edge-Chromium is coming soon. But I have no idea of the exact date. I'll inform you later if I have any news. Thanks for your understanding.